# How To write test method for ResultSetExtractor using mockito?

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito

How to write a method in myDAOTest class to test my DAOImpl Class using Mockito? here is the method which i need to test from my TestClass.

```
@Override
public myCustomResponse mymethod(String query, Map<String, Object> parameters) {

    jdbcTemplate.query(query, parameters, new ResultSetExtractor<List<MyObject>>() {

        @Override
        public List<MyObject> extractData(ResultSet result) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
            try {
                List<MyObject> myObject= new ArrayList<>();
                while (result.next()) {
                    response = getResponseDetails(result);
                }
                return myObject;
            } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
                LOG.debug(MyConstants.DATABASE_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE);
                throw new MyCustomeException(MyConstants.DATABASE_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    });

        }
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Possibility 1:**

Extract your ResultSetExtractor into it's own class, which makes it much simpler to test than as an anonymous inner class.

**Possibility 2:**

Mock the jdbcTemplate, create an ArgumentCaptor, call the method and then do...

```
Mockito.verify(this.jdbcTemplate).query(any(), any(), captor.capture());
```

This allows you to then get the ResultSetExtractor from the ArgumentCaptor and run tests on that. But this makes your whole test complex, so I still suggest possibility 1.

**Possibility 3:**

Test the whole thing against an in-memory database,testing the ResultSetExtractor only indirectly. Since this seems to be Spring, there are easy ways to do so, but of course, your unit test will now include a whole SpringApplicationContext, a db, etc. - which makes it slower than a "pure" unit test with only mocks. Since it's something that fires queries to a db, you will need to run it against a db anyway some time, otherwise your tests will not really be complete (simulating it via mocks is good for the basics, but not the same thing).